# How can I write this statement using EF Core 2.1?

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I'm switching my code from EF6 to EF Core 2.1 and I'm stuck on this line:

```
var pinnedJobIds = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>("Select JobId From UserJobsPinned Where UserId=@p0", userId).ToList();
```

I know that EF Core allows for this:

```
ctx.Jobs.FromSql("Select * From Jobs").ToList();
```

However, I can't figure out how to simply return the Id field instead of the entire Job record.

I saw something like this, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
var pinnedJobIds = ctx.Query<int>()
```

but I didn't get any option for FromSql on that.

How can I do this in EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

If Job is an entity type, you could write it like this:

```cs
var pinnedJobIds = ctx.Jobs
    .FromSql($"Select * From UserJobsPinned Where UserId={userId}")
    .Select(j => j.JobId)
    .ToList();
```